# iOS 8 afnetworking

Tags: ios8, afnetworking, nsmutabledictionary

I have an app which does download background work. I'm using AFNetworking 1.3 and AFDownloadRequestOperation to do this job. Every thing works fine until iOS 8 comes.
When the download task completed and the app ran into the complete block, the app crash!

I add some breakpoint in the code and found this line:

[aNSMutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"abc"];

this line of code runs again and again, but can't step out. At the second running time, the app is crash, seems like there is no object for the key "abc". 
This crash bug only happens under iOS8 and iOS 8.1. The whole part of code like follows:

```xcode
    DownloadTask *task = [DownloadTask new];
        task.totalBytesExpectedToWrite = 0;
        task.totalBytesWritten = 0;
        task.filename = item.mp3URL.lastPathComponent;
        task.title = item.title;
    [aNSMutableDictionary setValue:task forKey:@"abc"];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {        
            [aNSMutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"abc"];
            }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            [operation cancel];
            [aNSMutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"abc"];
            return ;
        }];
[aNSOperationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Does anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: 1.3 is history. The current version is 2.5.0. Update the library. That should resolve it.

Comment: I have changed my code to AFNetworking 2.5, but same error happened.

Comment: The last error in console are:NSScanner: nil string argument, NSScanner: nil string argument
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

Comment: I have fixed it by myself. It is caused by: I had added KVO on aNSMutableDictionary, when I removeObjectForkey from the aNSMutableDictionary, I must first remove the KVO. It's ok(dont remove the KVO before call removeObjectForKey) under iOS6,7, but cant work under iOS8.